# Angular ngModelChange and button to clear the input

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a text input used to search data on the backend.

When something is entered in the input, a clear button appear in order to reset the field value.
If I enter or remove characters in the input, I have a log indicating the content of the input.

However, if I click the button, the log is not triggered (I need it to query the unfiltered dataset from the server)

```
// app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  search = null;
    public searchSeries(value: string) {
      console.log(value); // this log is not called when the input is cleared via the button
  }
}
```

---

```
// app.component.html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" (ngModelChange)="searchSeries($event)" [(ngModel)]="search">
<button *ngIf="search"  aria-label="Clear" (click)="search=null">
    clear
</button>
```

How could I have the `searchSeries`function called when clearing the input via the `clear` button ?

Here is a stackblitz example showing the problem : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yk7wbc

Comment: `(click)="searchSeries()'`? or `(click)="clearSearch()"` then `clearSearch() { search = null; this.searchSeries();`? `clearSearch()` being a function in the component's `.ts` file.

Comment: @JDunken What you said is almost working, just adding `(click)="searchSeries('')"` on the button should solve the issue.

Comment: yes, indeed both solution solved the problem, guess I am tired to not have thought about that :) @JDunken If you bother to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @L.Faros answer posted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call functions with the ng `click` directive, like so...

```
<button *ngIf="search"  aria-label="Clear" (click)='someFunctionInTheComponentsTsFile()'>
    clear
</button>
```

You can then do what you like...

```
someFunctionInTheComponentsTsFile() {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `searchSeries` function on click the clear button:

```
<button *ngIf="search"  aria-label="Clear" (click)="searchSeries(search); search=null">
    clear
</button>
```